# Isapi additional url variables

Tags: url-rewriting, isapi

i wish to add more url variables to my url... whatever there is after ? i wish to retrieve it as a urls variable Thank YOU!

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).html?(.*)$ products.cfm?categ=$1&urls=$2   [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^products.cfm?categ=(.*)&urls=(.*)$ (.*).html?(.*) [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^condition=(\d+)&maxprice=(\d+)&minprice=(\d+)&persons=(\d+)&maxyear=(\d+)&minyear=(\d+)&order=(\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/(.*).html$ products.cfm?categ=$1&condition=%1&maxprice=%2&minprice=%3&persons=%4&maxyear=%5&minyear=%6&order=%7?   [NC,L]
```